# Macro which prints an expression and evaluates it (with __STRING)

Tags: c, expression-evaluation

For learning and demonstrating, I need a macro which prints its parameter **and** evaluates it. I suspect it is a very common case, may be even a FAQ but I cannot find actual references.

My current code is:

```
#define PRINT(expr) (fprintf(stdout, "%s -> %d\n", __STRING(expr), (expr)))
```

and then:

```
PRINT(x & 0x01);
```

It works fine but I am not sure of the legal status of the __STRING macro, specially since it is in the private __ namespace.

So, my questions:

1. Is there a better way to write this macro?
2. Is __STRING standard/great/evil?
3. How to use existing search tools to find about __STRING? SO's search engine just searches anything containing string :-(

Comment: I've had similar problems searching in the past. ".net" used to be a big one.

Comment: You can use google to search StackOverflow by using google's site: argument :) e.g. "__string site:stackoverflow.com" (which didn't return anything).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the # preprocessor token which converts the parameter following it to a string literal:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR(x) #x
#define PRINT(expr) (fprintf(stdout, "%s -> %d\n", STR(expr), (expr)))

int main(void)
{
    int x = 7;

    PRINT(x & 0x01);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

2. It's definitely not standard, and this is the first time I've come across it; not surprising as it doesn't seem to do much more than the STR() macro above, at a first glance.
3. [Google](http://www.google.com/search?&q=__string&btnG=Search) seems to work fine.

Comment: Indeed, just using #expr in the macro definition works fine. But, then what's the point of the __STRING macro that you find in many places (such as assert() source code)?

Comment: __STRING is just a wrapper around #. It's defined in cdefs.h

Answer (score 13):

Something like

```
#define PRINT(expr) (fprintf(stdout, "%s -> %d\n", #expr, (expr)))
```

is probably what you want. # is the stringification operator.

Answer (score 0):

It is **glibc** who has been providing `__STRING` since (at least) version 1.04 (1992-09-03), maybe earlier.

/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:

```
#define __CONCAT(x,y)   x ## y
#define __STRING(x) #x
```

They were both used in glibc back then. Currently, `__STRING` is not used in glibc, but is kept there for app use.

On Linux, you may rely upon these. IIUC, `__STRING` and `__CONCAT` were adopted in NetBSD 1.3; Solaris provides neither. Other OSes may vary.